# Combining aggregate functions in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, group-by

Assuming the following table and using sqlite I have the following question:

```
   Node |Loadcase |  Fx    | Cluster
   ---------------------------------
   1    |    1    |  50    |    A
   2    |    1    | -40    |    A
   3    |    1    |  60    |    B
   4    |    1    |  80    |    C
   1    |    2    |  50    |    A
   2    |    2    | -50    |    A
   3    |    2    |  80    |    B
   4    |    2    | -100   |    C
```

I am trying to write a query which fetches the maximum absolute value of Fx and the Load case for each Node 1-4.
An additional requirement is that Fx having the same Cluster shall be summed up before making this query .

In the example above I would expect the following results:

```
Node | Loadcase  | MaxAbsClusteredFx
-----|-----------|-------------------
1    |   1       |      10
2*   |           |
3    |   2       |      80
4    |   2       |     100
```

- N/A because summed up with node one. Both belonging to cluster A

Query:

For Node 1 I would execute a query similar to this

```
SELECT Loadcase,abs(Fx GROUP BY Cluster) FROM MyTable WHERE abs(Fx GROUP BY Cluster) = max(abs(Fx GROUP BY Cluster)) AND Node = 1
```

I keep getting " Error while executing query: near "Forces": syntax error " or alike. 
Thankful for any help!

Comment: `..An additional requirement is that Fx having the same Cluster shall be summed up before making this query..` not only I guess. I think the `group by` should by `node, cluster`.

Comment: No, Fx from  different loadcases shall not be grouped/mixed. The only value to decide the grouping is Cluster

Comment: The just-cluster approach *will* mix different loadcases also.

Comment: Correct, I did not notice that... but so will GROUP By node, cluster..

Comment: So use `cluster, loadcase`..it depends what do you want to group on.